# Why can't I "Full page" a js/html/css snippet in a new tab?

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

At the bottom of javascript/html/css code snippets, when clicking `Full page`, the current page is simply replaced with the full screen result of the snippet; and no way to get back to the post.

Neither the browser's "go back" arrow/button nor the return shortcut is available.

And neither the "open link in a new tab" right click option nor the ctrl/click shortcut is available on the `Full page` link/button.

[image]

The only way around consists in not forgetting that Ctrl/click will simply replace the page (which I still can't remember until it's too late) and instead open a new instance of the page in a new tab

Which makes my experience of this feature quite frustrating!

The question is: could this `Full page` link have the option to be opened in a new tab (via Ctrl/click shortcut and right click context menu).

---

Test it yourself:

```html
<html><div>Hello world</div></html>
```

---

Working with `Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS` and `Google Chrome Version 65.0.3325.146 (Official Build) (64-bit)` or `Firefox 60.0.1 (64-bit)`

Comment: I can't open snippets on meta in a new tab either but I *can* close full page snippets on main. I see a 'Close' link in the upper right hand corner, same place it appears on meta. (Return to post is under the snippet if I choose 'Expand Snippet')

Comment: Also, a link to a question with a snippet would be more useful than a screenshot.

Comment: Yes, I was about to edit and remove the note on the different behavior on meta, as it's because I simple clicked on "Full page". And yes! there is a `Close` button on the top right corner^^ Though I'd like to be able to open the snippet in another tab to be able to go back and forth between the post and the snippet

Comment: StackSnippets are not stored anywhere, they are directly populated by the main page (if you check in your dev-tools you'll see their iframe has no `src`). Might be possible to create a Blob version of the document though, and then use a Blob URI, which should allow opening in a new Tab. But note that you still wouldn't be able to share this URI.